# The method in the type is not applicable for the argument in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a jar file which I have decompiled and trying to run it in eclipse to debug one issue.
I have created a main function as below

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    InterAcctInqServiceProvider inter = new InterAcctInqServiceProvider();
    IUsbMessage a = inter.executeOutboundRequest("test");
}
```

On running in eclipse I am getting error **The method executeOutboundRequest(IUsbMessage) in the type InterAcctInqServiceProvider is not applicable for the arguments (String)**

Below is the complete code. Please let me know how can I call executeOutboundRequest method and pass a string in that

```
/*     */ import com.ibm.ci.fiusb.app.AbstractOutboundServiceProvider;
/*     */ import com.ibm.ci.fiusb.app.UsbMessageFactory;
/*     */ import com.ibm.ci.fiusb.common.IUsbMessage;
/*     */ import com.ibm.ci.fiusb.common.NVPVO;

public IUsbMessage executeOutboundRequest(IUsbMessage paramIUsbMessage)
/*     */   {
/*  48 */     IUsbMessage localIUsbMessage = UsbMessageFactory.createUbusMessage();
/*     */     try
/*     */     {
/*  51 */       LogManager.logDebug("ServiceProvider:- Enter executeOutboundRequest");
/*  52 */       Object[] arrayOfObject = (Object[])paramIUsbMessage.getPayload();
/*  53 */       NVPVO localNVPVO = (NVPVO)arrayOfObject[1];
/*  54 */       String str1 = (String)localNVPVO.getHashmap().get("endPointUrl");
/*  55 */       String str2 = (String)localNVPVO.getHashmap().get("respTag");
/*  56 */       String str3 = (String)localNVPVO.getHashmap().get("body");
/*  57 */       str3 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><FIXML xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.bank.com/fixml AcctInq.xsd\" xmlns=\"http://www.bank.com/fixml\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">" + str3.trim();
/*  58 */       LogManager.logDebug("ServiceProvider:- RequestXMLMsg" + str3);
/*  59 */       MessageFactory localMessageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
/*  60 */       SOAPMessage localSOAPMessage1 = localMessageFactory.createMessage();
/*     */       
/*  62 */       SOAPFactory localSOAPFactory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
/*  63 */       SOAPBody localSOAPBody = localSOAPMessage1.getSOAPBody();
/*  64 */       SOAPElement localSOAPElement1 = localSOAPBody.addChildElement(localSOAPFactory.createName("executeService"));
/*  65 */       SOAPElement localSOAPElement2 = localSOAPElement1.addChildElement(localSOAPFactory.createName("arg_0_0"));
/*  66 */       localSOAPElement2.addTextNode(str3);
/*  67 */       localSOAPMessage1.saveChanges();
/*     */       
/*  69 */       localSOAPMessage1.writeTo(System.out);
/*     */       
/*     */ 
/*     */     catch (Exception localException)
/*     */     {
/* 173 */       // Some code
/*     */     }
/*     */     
/* 183 */     return localIUsbMessage;
/*     */   }
/*     */ 

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    InterAcctInqServiceProvider inter = new InterAcctInqServiceProvider();
    IUsbMessage a = inter.executeOutboundRequest("test");
}

}
```

Comment: You can't. That method expects an `IUsbMessage` parameter you can't just give it a string,

Comment: @greg-449 How do I pass data of type IUsbMessage? Data which needs to be passed is a simple xml

Answer (score 0):

```
   String str = "test" 
   Message msg = Message.obtain();
   msg.obj = str;
   IUsbMessage a = inter.executeOutboundRequest(msg);
```

Add this in the Main Method as you are trying to pass String in a Message type.

Comment: Getting error on Message.obtain() - The method obtain() is undefined for the type Message